# Using Countifs to count number of values in a range getting an Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

Working on a Google Spreadsheet seems to be behaving strangely.

I'm getting the error Array arguments to `COUNTIFS` are of different size.

this formula works fine for me.

```
=COUNTIFS(Bookings!R:R,"<>",Bookings!AI:AI,month(A:A),Bookings!AJ:AJ,year(A:A))
```

but this one gives the error:

```
=COUNTIFS(Bookings!R:R,"<>", month(Bookings!D:D), month(A:A), year(Bookings!D:D), year(A:A))
```

I have a date in the D column while in the column AI I have a month 12 and in AJ I have a year like 2019.

Would love to get some insight on how to solve this.

Comment: Neither formula seems to be correct. If you see the example provided by Google for this formula, it says `COUNTIFS(A1:A10, ">20", B1:B10, "<30")`. The inequality sign can't be a separate parameter. Can you explain a bit about what you are trying to match (or not match)?

Comment: the first one is matching a taking a date from column A and counts the rows that are in that month.

in the second one im trying to do the same, but this time the match isnt directly to a month 12 and year 2019, but i'm trying to get the month and year from a date cell.
makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

let the Bookings sheet be:

[image: 0]

---

then you need to do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), COUNTIFS(Bookings!R2:R, "<>", 
                               MONTH(Bookings!D2:D), MONTH(A2:A),
                                YEAR(Bookings!D2:D), YEAR(A2:A)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: For the first one I get this error "Error
Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (36)."

and I get the previous error on the second one.

Any idea?

Comment: its a bit tricky to strip out all the data ... there is a lot of sensitive stuff in here.
is there another way you can think i can share more information?

Comment: Is there a simple way to count only for that month and not paste for the next ones?
https://www.loom.com/share/027b5c4148214976871c3827a59bae6a

Comment: @Ron https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dD5ETf4-2Sc-7z1EmcuquY7WqZury3jXqI1sQwkntL4/edit#gid=806931236

Comment: Nothing happens when i paste it - see https://www.loom.com/share/401033c5868c4f648bbc366e749e3993

Comment: so strange, I came back now after 2 hours, and it does work .. I guess it took forever to apply.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Any idea why this formula returns 0 in all the cells?


=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), SUMIFS(Bookings!R2:R, MONTH(Bookings!D2:D), MONTH(A2:A),
                                      YEAR(Bookings!D2:D), YEAR(A2:A)), ))

Column R has the amount and I want to sum if the months' match, similar to the count before

Comment: I added my formula here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dD5ETf4-2Sc-7z1EmcuquY7WqZury3jXqI1sQwkntL4/edit#gid=601771802

it also brings 0's

Comment: `SUMIFS` rarely works with a combination of `ArrayFormula`. therefore use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A), QUERY({IF(LEN(Bookings!D2:D), TEXT(Bookings!D2:D, "mmm yyyy"), ), Bookings!R2:R}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0), 2, 0)))` - sheet updated

Comment: Thank you.

is there a simple way to add multiple conditions .. like this one - =SUMIFS(Bookings!R:R,Bookings!AB:AB,"TTC",Bookings!G:G,"",Bookings!AI:AI,month(A:A),Bookings!AJ:AJ,year(A:A))

inside the vlookup?

Comment: we can also just drop the arrayformula and paste the function in every cell if it makes life easy

Comment: as already mentioned you need to use query instead of sumifs. and yes, you can add multiple conditions, you just need to include it in range and then state the condition under `where` clause or more easier filter it before it goes to query

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dD5ETf4-2Sc-7z1EmcuquY7WqZury3jXqI1sQwkntL4/edit#gid=0&range=T2 where I added condition for example

Comment: why are the results show on the right side? and not under like before?